# simple ping from remote agent

Tags: ping, agent

I have been looking around to see if there is some simple, stand-alone(ish) agent/server setup that would allow a ping to be launched from a host with an agent on it. When I say "ping," I mean via icmp echo and/or tcp port check. I have Windows, Linux, and AIX systems that would get such an agent.

I would like to set up a central server with authentication that can issue pings *from* any device that has one of these agents. The primary use would be VPN testing, so that traffic can be initiated from a device that I don't necessarily have access to.

It seems that some monitoring software has this (e.g., Zabbix) but I don't want to go through the pain of installing a whole big piece of software like that just to get this functionality.

Almost all our AIX and Linux systems have perl installed, so that could be a nice option if I had to write my own. I would rather find something "tried-and-true" though...

Comment: _"central server with authentication that can issue pings from any device that has one of these agents"_ do you mean that can issue pings _to_ any device? How about setting up a cronjob on the centralized server, calling a script to read the host list from a file and issue a ping to each one?

Comment: @kajahno no, I meant that it could reach through to a server and force THAT server to issue a ping somewhere. We solved the problem with [Salt](https://saltstack.com).

Comment: nice one! Will try Salt, using Ansible at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that we already had SaltStack installed on almost all our servers (I'm a network guy, not a server guy). Once I talked to one of the server administrators, he showed me how this could be done using [Salt](https://saltstack.com).